# How to dynamically reload nginx config

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, sftp

I'm currently trying to setup Nginx for a domain with production, testing and development stages. Each comes with it's own partial Nginx config file with rewrites.

The production and testing stages are set up as branches from a Git repository and automatic reloading of these configurations in Git's post-receive hook. This all works just fine.

The development stage I'd like to transmit using SFTP using Netbeans' "SFTP-on-save" as I don't need version control at this granularity and it's a bit more direct. However, here I have no such thing as git's post-receive hook to trigger Nginx to reload config upon upload.

In Apache, .htaccess files would just load dynamically. Is there anything similar in Nginx and/or how could I simulate this? Ideally a solution that reloads the config files only and immediately when changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't use a post-receive hook, perhaps you can use `inotify` to watch for changes in the nginx configuration.

In this case, you would use `incrond` and `incrontab` to set up a watch on specified files and actions to take when those files change.  Something like this in the `incrontab`:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf IN_MODIFY /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Here's the [man page for incrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab).  You should be able to find other documentation and examples for using the `inotify` toolset that will fit your configuration.

Comment: Would it be possible to match for a wildcard? "Like /var/www/*/nginx.*.conf" or "nginx.*"?

Answer (score 3):

As cjc said, `inotify` and `service nginx reload` are the commands you are looking for.

Check out [this post from nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) which gives a great explanation on how to configure inotify.